# Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet

Tags: git, undo, git-merge

I accidentally ran `git merge some_other_branch` on my local master branch. I haven't pushed the changes to origin master. How do I undo the merge?

---

After merging, `git status` says:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
```

How do I undo all these commits?

Comment: If you need to preserve the history, in other words there is a change that anyone has ever pulled from you or you have pushed it somewhere use the solution in Yuri Ushakov answer down below!

Comment: Please unselect the current winning answer, it's unsafe (as many pointed out) though still gathering votes. To me "MBO"-s looks the best, although it has way fewer points.

Comment: [If you need to **preserve history**, use *Yuri*'s solution down below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6217372/274502)! (just adding a link to @Sedrik comment)

Comment: Related: [Revert to a previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095/456814).

Comment: This is a great resource straight from Github: [How to undo \(almost\) anything with Git](https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git)

Comment: Git - a story of 3 trees (head, index, and working tree explained in a very helpful way): [Reset Demystified](https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html)

Answer (score 5499, accepted):

With `git reflog` check which commit is one prior the merge (`git reflog` will be a better option than `git log`). Then you can reset it using:

```
git reset --hard commit_sha
```

There's also another way:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

It will get you back 1 commit.

**Be aware that any modified and uncommitted/unstashed files will be reset to their unmodified state**. To keep them either stash changes away or see `--merge` option below.

---

As @Velmont suggested below in his answer, in this direct case using:

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

might yield better results, as it should preserve your changes. `ORIG_HEAD` will point to a commit directly before merge has occurred, so you don't have to hunt for it yourself.

---

A further tip is to use the `--merge` switch instead of `--hard` since it doesn't reset files unnecessarily:

```
git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD
```

> --merge
>
> Resets the index and updates the files in the working tree that are different between <commit> and HEAD, but keeps those which are different between the index and working tree (i.e. which have changes which have not been added).

Comment: I don't think this will (always?) work -- the "one prior the merge" will be the most recent commit that was merged in from the other branch -- it won't be the most recent commit on the current branch. Right? (This might just be a result of what `git log` chooses to show by default -- maybe there is a different output of `git log` or `git reflog` could be used for this)

Comment: I think it might depend whether you squash merge.

Comment: In my case, git log showed a merge commit and listed the two parent commits that were merged to result in the merge commit.  I used git log to determine which of the parent commits listed belonged to the branch I merged in to the current branch, and then reset to the other commit (since that had to be the current branch's HEAD prior to the merge).  I would be wary of doing using the `HEAD~#` notation, since you probably don't know how many commits were brought in with the merge.

Comment: @JohnBachir is right. In the `git log` output, you want to look at the two parent commits. One is the latest commit in your branch, one is the latest commit in the branch you merged into. You want to `git reset --hard` to the parent commit on the branch you merged into.

Comment: @JohnBachir: As long as the "merge" isn't really a fast forward, it will result in a new commit that is at the top of the log, and this commit has two parents (or more than 2 if you do an octopus merge). If you remove this one merge commit, then all of the older commits that came in from the merge will disappear, too. To be safe, though, after a reset git will tell you where the new head is: "HEAD is now at 88a04de <commit message>". I always look at that to make sure that I ended up where I expected to be. My project uses a standard branch naming scheme to keep things memorable.

Comment: What i found useful was to look at "git reflog" and look for the last commit that i did in master.  Then do `git reset --hard <commit_sha>`

Comment: I think if it is a FF merge you would probably be best off with something like:
git reset --keep master@{1}

Comment: `git branch -a -v` will show you all local and remote branches and their SHAs, so use the SHA for remote/master if you want to match that

Comment: Maybe this **warning** should go into the answer itself: [***Always avoid rewriting git history!***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491001/what-are-the-practical-consequences-of-rewriting-git-history)

Comment: Using HEAD~N doesn't work for large N, and finding commit hash is a pain for large N

Comment: if the merge was the last state change `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` will work too -- otherwise use `git reflog` to find the sha or revision reference you want.  see also `man gitrevisions`

Comment: Instead of doing manual work, you could do the line in my answer below which should always work without the manual bits.

Comment: @Velmont: what you don't notice is that my answer is now 4 (FOUR) years old. Remind me: how much git has evolved from that time? Aye, I'll update the answer since you are correct :)

Comment: @MarcinGil ORIG_HEAD existed at least in 2009 :) Which is 5 years ago.

Comment: @Velmont but AFAIR not --merge ;) Anyway your answer is cool.

Comment: "git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD" just lost a ton of my changes :-\

Comment: `git reset --hard` will also discard any local modifications irreversibly in addition to walk back in history. `git reset --keep` resets the history while preserving local changes if any, much safer.

Comment: I had done worse, I changed the origin without paying attention. Fortunately it is to solve! **---** `--- git reset --hard [sha-commit-before-merge]
git push [origin] [branch] --force` **---**  [source](https://coderwall.com/p/o0krbw/undo-a-git-merge-that-has-been-pushed-to-the-server)

Comment: You can also do `git reset --hard origin/master` instead of specifying a commit sha.

Comment: @MarcinGil Could you please update the answer to say that YOU WILL LOSE CODE with git reset --hard? Or make git reset --merge the top part of the answer, rather than the end? I just lost some changes. They were relatively trivial, but for the next person they might not be.

Comment: @skypecakes: well I would assume that if someone wants to do "undo" - one expects some changes are reverted/lost. Anyway I'm curious of the scenario how have you performed the reset if you lost changes. Only the merge commit itself should be removed, nothing more.

Comment: @MarcinGil The code I lost was (in my mind) not related to the undo. It was a set of modified files whose changes had never been committed. Changes I'd been sitting on for a month or so; not needed yet, but possibly useful in the future. After the git reset, those changes disappeared. None of those changed files were involved in the merge (or I'd have gotten errors during the merge operation). I'd been moving between branches all this time leaving those changes uncommitted, and git never seemed to care, so it surprised me that suddenly it removed them.

Comment: @skypecakes Sorry for your lost code but sitting for a month on an changed and uncommitted code (even locally, not pushed) is for me truly unbelievable. I would strongly advise to read the Git Book if you haven't been even expecting what reset could do. Anyway sure, I can add a warning.

Comment: @MarcinGil Thanks for adding that warning! I wasn't looking for an apology; like I said, it's no big deal for me. But for someone else it might be. And thanks for the suggestion, I will read the Git Book when I get a chance.

Comment: This is a great resource straight from Github: [How to undo \(almost\) anything with Git](https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git)

Comment: please menation ORIG_HEAD method first, it is more likely what people want

Comment: "git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD" might actually NOT preserve your changes. Maybe better warn about that.

Comment: This only reset the local copy.  When you then try to push to apply the change to GitHub you get an error: "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind."  This message suggests gt pull. If you follow the suggestion the you end up right where you left off. Thus this answer is incomplete. What magical incantation do you need to push to GitHub?

Comment: generally "git reset --hard" works alone if you want to go back to the last commit

Comment: I had the same situation, I merged and then immediately wanted to revert back.  The command I gave was :    `git reset --hard HEAD~0`  and not HEAD~1, the result was exactly what I wanted, revrting back to the same state before the merge command.

Comment: This answer by @Parris with example is really helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/27571343/8265811

Answer (score 1703):

Assuming your local master was not ahead of origin/master, you should be able to do

```
git reset --hard origin/<branch-name>
```

So assuming you did this on `master`, then your local `master` branch should look identical to `origin/master`.

Comment: @Carter it actually is not the best answer. It is possible that origin/master may be ahead of your local master just previous to the merge by some commits, in that case this might not give the desired results

Comment: @dhruva-sagar Yes, but as long as git doesn't say you're behind, and you don't fetch, you should be fine.

Comment: This is great, but if you did a remote auto-merge (e.g. merge pull request on github), then you'll need to reset to a commit (accepted answer).

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect if (and only if) you have a remote repository.

Comment: How could I do it if I don't have the remote reference?, do `git reflog` to find where I was previous merge and then `git reset --hard HEAD@{some_number}` work?

Comment: No it's not the perfect one for this question, see the "assume" clause. MBO's answer actually covers this case, and the case where the merge is not the only local commit.

Comment: Yes it is the best answer if you read the last sentence of his question: `I don't want my branch to be ahead by any number of commits. How do I get back to that point?`, it seems like he wants to get back to what origin/master points to.

Comment: Once again, maybe this **warning** should go into the answer itself: [***Always avoid rewriting git history!***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491001/what-are-the-practical-consequences-of-rewriting-git-history)

Comment: My answer does the same thing, but is much safer. :) You don't need all the "assuming" stuff.

Comment: This is a great resource straight from Github: [How to undo \(almost\) anything with Git](https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git)

Comment: git reset --hard origin/<your-branch>

Comment: Instead always resetting the origin/master you could do `git reset --hard @{u}`

Answer (score 1252):

See [chapter 4 in the Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things) and [the original post by Linus Torvalds](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Git/Git-26/src/git-htmldocs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).

To undo a merge **that was already pushed**:

```
git revert -m 1 commit_hash
```

Be sure to revert the revert if you're committing the branch again, like Linus said.

Comment: @perfectionist agreed :)  Kind of wish there was a way to migrate this answer to another question-- (maybe there is?)

Comment: for more information about revert: [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/undoing-changes#!revert)

Comment: To be confident that this revert has worked, you can do **git diff hash1 hash2** where hash1 is the committed revert, and hash2 is the old commit whose state you were trying to get back to. No output == success!

I was able to roll back multiple commits by doing this multiple times, starting by reverting the most recent merge and working backwards. **git diff** showed me that I ended up in the state I wanted.

Comment: Notice that **this does *not* actually solve the original poster's question**. The original poster ***already*** used `git revert -m 1 <commit>`. The problem is that doing that doesn't erase the accidental merge that he did (and hasn't pushed yet). The other answers involving hard resets are better for the original poster's problem.

Comment: This is a great resource straight from Github: [How to undo \(almost\) anything with Git](https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git)

Comment: This was right answer!

Answer (score 1160):

It is strange that the simplest command was missing. Most answers work, but undoing the merge you just did, **this is the easy and safe way**:

```
git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD
```

The ref `ORIG_HEAD` will point to the original commit from before the merge.

(The `--merge` option has nothing to do with the merge. It's just like `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`, but safer since it doesn't touch uncommitted changes.)

Comment: If you've dirtied your working tree since, `git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD` preserves those changes.

Comment: This is the *only* correct answer (I'm not saying this is the best answer - note the difference). Let's say, on master, I did 3 commits at t1, t3, and t5. Let's say, on branch1, I did 3 comments at t2, t4 and t6 (assume t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 and t6 are in chronological order). Any command similar to `git reset --hard HEAD~5` will only reset HEAD (may remove commits in both master and branch1). Only the `--merge` option removes the `merge`.

Comment: @Manu The `--merge` option doesn't actually remove the merge, you can use `--hard` it will also work well.  It's the reference ORIG_HEAD that's the clue here, it is set before you do a merge to where you are standing at that point. :)

Comment: @yingted what do u mean by "If you've dirtied your working tree since, git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD preserves those changes." Did u mean changing the files after merging ? Anyway i did the merge and then did some of resolving conflicts. But then i wanted to reset the merge and did as instructed in this answer. Everything was ok and it has not preserved my changes done after the merge. My local repo is just similar to the position before I did the merge.

Comment: The `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD` command worked perfectly for me – it may have been helped by the fact that I didn't make any other changes to the repository after the local `git merge` I was trying to undo. The command simply reset the state of the repository back to how it was before the merge. Thanks for the great tip!

Answer (score 487):

With newer Git versions, if you have not committed the merge yet *and you have a merge conflict*, you can simply do:

```
git merge --abort
```

From `man git merge`:

> [This] can only be run after the merge has resulted in conflicts. `git merge --abort` will abort the merge process and try to reconstruct the pre-merge state.

Comment: His merge is committed but not pushed (see title), he has already merged, your command works only when he is still in the middle of a merge

Answer (score 184):

You should reset to the previous commit. This should work:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Or even `HEAD^^` to revert that revert commit. You can always give a full SHA reference if you're not sure how many steps back you should take.

In case when you have problems and your master branch didn't have any local changes, you can reset to `origin/master`.

Comment: The best answer IMHO, incorporates the OP's own one (assuming only 1 step to revert, which seemed to be the case in the Q), as well as randomguy3's shortcut one(which works when "your master branch didn't had any local changes")

Comment: You commenters, @Inger and @Konstantin, why? You came here after my answer was created, and it is more correct. Just going up the HEAD one step is often wrong, and you'd have to actually count how far up you need to go. Git already sets `ORIG_HEAD` for you, why not use it?

Comment: will it reset local changes as well ? #PleaseUpdate.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, resetting head like that makes much more sense than half the answers here.

Comment: HEAD^ equals commit prior to HEAD?   and ^^ is two commits prior?   Guessing this won't work with fast forward merges?

Answer (score 103):

Lately, I've been using `git reflog` to help with this. This mostly only works if the merge JUST happened, and it was on your machine.

`git reflog` might return something like:

```
fbb0c0f HEAD@{0}: commit (merge): Merge branch 'master' into my-branch
43b6032 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to my-branch
e3753a7 HEAD@{2}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
e3753a7 HEAD@{3}: pull --rebase: checkout e3753a71d92b032034dcb299d2df2edc09b5830e
b41ea52 HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD^
8400a0f HEAD@{5}: rebase: aborting
```

The first line indicates that a merge occurred. The 2nd line is the time before my merge. I simply `git reset --hard 43b6032` to force this branch to track from before the merge, and carry-on.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Needed to undo a merge but the other answers just messed it up more, using `reflog` to get the SHA and pass that into `git reset` worked.

Answer (score 84):

If you are in a middle of merging you can always abort it

```
git merge --abort
```

Comment: thanks bro and i was about to do that scary stuff correct answer. lucky i scrolled down. i just want to delete merge head

Answer (score 60):

With modern Git, you can:

```
git merge --abort
```

Older syntax:

```
git reset --merge
```

Old-school:

```
git reset --hard
```

But actually, it is worth noticing that `git merge --abort` is only equivalent to `git reset --merge` given that `MERGE_HEAD` is present. This can be read in the Git help for merge command.

```
git merge --abort is equivalent to git reset --merge when MERGE_HEAD is present.
```

After a failed merge, when there is no `MERGE_HEAD`, the failed merge can be undone with `git reset --merge`, but not necessarily with `git merge --abort`, **so they are not only old and new syntax for the same thing**.

Personally I find `git reset --merge` much more powerful and useful in everyday work, so that's the one I always use.

Comment: Worked great for me. Every other post says this is so complicated, but this did exactly what is expected. I suppose it only worked because there were conflicts, which doesn't exactly answer the original question.

Comment: This answer doesn't focus on the OP's situation, and leaves out important context.

Comment: Thanks! `git reset --merge` helped after a failed `git apply --3way`, when the other answers didn't.  This seems to be because there is no MERGE_HEAD.

Answer (score 59):

If branches are merged and not pushed, then git reset command given below will work to undo the merge:

```
git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD
```

Example:

```
git reset --merge origin/master
```

Comment: Example : git reset --merge origin/master

Answer (score 43):

Okay, the answers other people here gave me were close, but it didn't work. Here's what I did.

Doing this...

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git status
```

...gave me the following status.

```
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 3 and 3 different commit(s) each, respectively.
```

I then had to type in the same `git reset` command several more times.  Each time I did that, the message changed by one as you can see below.

```
> git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at [...truncated...]
> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 3 and 3 different commit(s) each, respectively.
> git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at [...truncated...]
> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 2 and 3 different commit(s) each, respectively.
> git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at [...truncated...]
> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 3 different commit(s) each, respectively.
> git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at [...truncated...]
> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 3 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

At this point, I saw the status message changed, so I tried doing a `git pull`, and that seemed to work:

```
> git pull
Updating 2df6af4..12bbd2f
Fast forward
 app/views/truncated |    9 ++++++---
 app/views/truncated |   13 +++++++++++++
 app/views/truncated |    2 +-
 3 files changed, 20 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
> git status
# On branch master
```

So long story short, my commands came down to this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git reset --hard HEAD^
git reset --hard HEAD^
git reset --hard HEAD^
git pull
```

Comment: or you could've used `HEAD^^^^`

Comment: maybe even reset to `origin/master` ;)

Answer (score 40):

**You have to change your HEAD, Not yours of course but git HEAD....**

So before answering let's add some background, explaining what is this `HEAD`.

## ***`First of all what is HEAD?`***

`HEAD` is simply a reference to the current commit (latest) on the current branch.
There can only be a single `HEAD` at any given time. (excluding `git worktree`)

The content of `HEAD` is stored inside `.git/HEAD` and it contains the 40 bytes SHA-1 of the current commit.

---

## ***`detached HEAD`***

If you are not on the latest commit - meaning that `HEAD` is pointing to a prior commit in history its called ***`detached HEAD`***.

[image]

On the command line, it will look like this- SHA-1 instead of the branch name since the `HEAD` is not pointing to the tip of the current branch

[image]

### [image]

#### A few options on how to recover from a detached HEAD:

---

#### [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

```
git checkout <commit_id>
git checkout -b <new branch> <commit_id>
git checkout HEAD~X // x is the number of commits t go back
```

This will checkout new branch pointing to the desired commit.
This command will checkout to a given commit.
At this point, you can create a branch and start to work from this point on.

```
# Checkout a given commit. 
# Doing so will result in a `detached HEAD` which mean that the `HEAD`
# is not pointing to the latest so you will need to checkout branch
# in order to be able to update the code.
git checkout <commit-id>

# create a new branch forked to the given commit
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

---

#### [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

You can always use the `reflog` as well.
`git reflog` will display any change which updated the `HEAD` and checking out the desired reflog entry will set the `HEAD` back to this commit.

**Every time the HEAD is modified there will be a new entry in the `reflog`**

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```

This will get you back to your desired commit

[image]

---

#### ***[`git reset --hard <commit_id>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)***

"Move" your HEAD back to the desired commit.

```sh
# This will destroy any local modifications.
# Don't do it if you have uncommitted work you want to keep.
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32

# Alternatively, if there's work to keep:
git stash
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
git stash pop
# This saves the modifications, then reapplies that patch after resetting.
# You could get merge conflicts if you've modified things which were
# changed since the commit you reset to.
```

- Note: ([Since Git 2.7](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt))
  you can also use the `git rebase --no-autostash` as well.

---

#### ***[`git revert <sha-1>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)***

"Undo" the given commit or commit range.
The reset command will "undo" any changes made in the given commit.
A new commit with the undo patch will be committed while the original commit will remain in the history as well.

```sh
# add new commit with the undo of the original one.
# the <sha-1> can be any commit(s) or commit range
git revert <sha-1>
```

---

This schema illustrates which command does what.
As you can see there `reset && checkout` modify the `HEAD`.

[image]

Comment: This is treasure ‍‍‍

Comment: @CodeWizard what is color scheme of your terminal ? Remind me ZX Spectrum colors, or you have manually set it ?

Answer (score 29):

It can be done multiple ways.

**1) Abort Merge**

If you are in-between a bad merge (mistakenly done with wrong branch), and wanted to avoid the merge to go back to the branch latest as below:

```
git merge --abort
```

**2) Reset HEAD to remote branch**

If you are working from remote develop branch, you can reset HEAD to the last commit on remote branch as below:

```
git reset --hard origin/develop
```

**3) Delete current branch, and checkout again from the remote repository**

Considering, you are working on develop branch in local repo, that syncs with remote/develop branch, you can do as below:

```
git checkout master 
##to delete one branch, you need to be on another branch, otherwise you will fall with the branch :) 

git branch -D develop
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
```

Comment: that "1) Abort Merge" was pretty enough. Upvoting.

Comment: Be careful!  git merge --abort "can only be run after the merge has resulted in conflicts. git merge --abort will abort the merge process and try to reconstruct the pre-merge state"

Comment: `git reset --hard origin/develop` this was what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 29):

if no conflict and merge completed then:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

if while doing a merge got conflict then abort will take you out of the recent merge changes:

```
git merge --abort
```

or if you want to revert back to a specific commit id .

```
git reset --hard <commit-id>
```

Answer (score 25):

You could use `git reflog` to find the previous checkout. Sometimes that's a good state you want to return back to.

Concretely,

```
$ git reflog
$ git reset --hard HEAD@{0}
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved half a day of my work. However I could not exit reflog mode with any command.

Comment: @Katarzyna use the "q" key to exit from reflog

Answer (score 21):

I was able to resolve this problem with a single command that doesn't involve looking up a commit id.

```
git reset --hard remotes/origin/HEAD
```

The accepted answer didn't work for me but this command achieved the results I was looking for.

Comment: Exactly! It resets your changes to the HEAD of the branch! Not doing one by one

Comment: didn't work for me. actually ended up sending local branch back a month or two. Thankfully this is all local so i can always destroy the branch and fetch it again. Just wanted to point that out in case others tried this.

Comment: @MattPengelly this method is largely undocumented and usually works if your branch is in sync with the remote branch before you did the merge.  Has it been months since your branch was in sync with the remote branch?

Comment: @MattPengelly it also depends on what branch the HEAD is pointed to. I'm using gitflow on one of my projects, and even though I'm on the develop branch, the remotes/origin/HEAD is pointed to origin/master so if I needed to undo a merge I would probably need to reset to remotes/origin/develop

Answer (score 16):

If you didn't commit it yet, you can only use

```
$ git checkout -f
```

It will undo the merge (and everything that you did).

Comment: Tried this and it actually increased the number of commits that my local branch is ahead.

Answer (score 16):

Got to this question also looking to revert to match origin (ie, NO commits ahead of origin). Researching further, found there's a `reset` command for exactly that:

`git reset --hard @{u}`

Note: `@{u}` is shorthand for `origin/master`. (And, of course, you need that remote repository for this to work.)

Answer (score 15):

Answering the question "**Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet**"

> You can use `git reset --hard HEAD~1`

Consider the following situation where there are 2 branches **master** and **feature-1**:

---

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --all
```

[image]

> **Do Git merge**

```
$ git merge feature-1
```

---

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --all
```

[image]

> **Undo Git merge**

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

---

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --all
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can use only two commands to revert a merge or restart by a specific commit:

1. `git reset --hard commitHash` (you should use the commit that you want to restart, eg. 44a587491e32eafa1638aca7738)
2. `git push origin HEAD --force` (Sending the new local master branch to origin/master)

Good luck and go ahead!

Answer (score 12):

The simplest answer is the one given by odinho - Velmont

First do `git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD`

For those looking to reset after changes are pushed, do this
(Because this is the first post seen for any git reset merge questions)

`git push origin HEAD --force`

This will reset in a way that you won't get the merged changes back again after pull.

Answer (score 12):

Use this command to abort a merge:

```
git merge --abort
```

Answer (score 11):

Just for an extra option to look at, I've been mostly following the branching model described here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ and as such have been merging with `--no-ff` (no fast forward) usually.

I just read this page as I'd accidentally merged a testing branch instead of my release branch with master for deploying (website, master is what is live).  The testing branch has two other branches merged to it and totals about six commits.

So to revert the whole commit I just needed one `git reset --hard HEAD^` and it reverted the whole merge.  Since the merges weren't fast forwarded the merge was a block and one step back is "branch not merged".

Answer (score 9):

If your merge and the corresponding commits were not pushed yet, you can always switch to another branch, delete the original one and re-create it.

For example, I accidentally merged a develop branch into master and wanted to undo that. Using the following steps:

```
git checkout develop
git branch -D master
git branch -t master origin/master
```

Voila! Master is at the same stage as origin, and your mis-merged state is erased.

Comment: Note: This not only undoes the merge but also any local commits that were made since the latest push to origin.

Answer (score 6):

**Strategy:** Create a new branch from where everything was good.

**Rationale:** Reverting a merge is hard. There are too many solutions, depending on many factors such as whether you've committed or pushed your merge or if there were new commits since your merge. Also you still need to have a relatively deep understanding of git to adapt these solutions to your case. If you blindly follow some instructions, you can end up with an "empty merge" where nothing will be merged, and further merge attempts will make Git tell you "Already up to date".

**Solution:**

Let's say you want to merge `dev` into `feature-1`.

1. Find the revision that you want to receive the merge:

   ```
   git log --oneline feature-1
   a1b2c3d4 Merge branch 'dev' into 'feature-1' <-- the merge you want to undo
   e5f6g7h8 Fix NPE in the Zero Point Module <-- the one before the merge, you probably want this one
   ```
2. Check it out (go back in time):

   ```
   git checkout e5f6g7h8
   ```
3. Create a new branch from there and check it out:

   ```
   git checkout -b feature-1
   ```

Now you can restart your merge:

1. Merge: `git merge dev`
2. Fix your merge conflicts.
3. Commit: `git commit`
4. When you're satisfied with the results, delete the old branch: `git branch --delete feature-1`

Answer (score 5):

If you want a command-line solution, I suggest to just go with MBO's answer.

If you're a newbie, you might like the graphical approach:

1. Kick off `gitk` (from the command line, or right click in file browser if you have that)
2. You can easily spot the merge commit there - the first node from the top with two parents
3. Follow the link to the first/left parent (the one on your current branch before the merge, usually red for me)
4. On the selected commit, right-click "Reset branch  to here", pick the hard reset there

Answer (score 5):

Just create new branch, then cherry-pick desired commits to it.

Its saver and simpler then resets described in many answers above

Comment: I agree with this suggestion, especially if you are not entirely comfortable with the git commands listed. This may be slower with more "toil", but if it doesn't come up much and you are concerned with losing your work, it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do `git rebase -i [hash] [branch_name]`  where `[hash]` is the identifying hash for however far back you want to rewind plus one (or however many commits back you want to go) and then delete the lines for the commits in the editor that you don't want any more. Save the file. Exit. Pray. And it should be rewound. You might have to do a `git reset --hard`, but it should be good at this point. You can also use this to pull specific commits out of a stack, if you don't want to keep them in your history, but that can leave your repository in a state that you probably don't want.

Comment: Just one detail, interactive rebase lets drop commits by deleting lines, but if you remove everything, rebase will be simply aborted. Easiest trick here is removing all lines but one, and label this last one as "drop" so everything is discarded.

Answer (score 2):

1. First, make sure that you've committed everything.
2. Then reset your repository to the previous working state:

   ```
   $ git reset f836e4c1fa51524658b9f026eb5efa24afaf3a36
   ```

   or using `--hard` (**this will remove all local, not committed changes!**):

   ```
   $ git reset f836e4c1fa51524658b9f026eb5efa24afaf3a36 --hard
   ```

   Use the hash which was there before your wrongly merged commit.
3. Check which commits you'd like to re-commit on the top of the previous correct version by:

   ```
   $ git log 4c3e23f529b581c3cbe95350e84e66e3cb05704f

   commit 4c3e23f529b581c3cbe95350e84e66e3cb05704f

   ...

   commit 16b373a96b0a353f7454b141f7aa6f548c979d0a

   ...
   ```
4. Apply your right commits on the top of the right version of your repository by:

   - By using cherry-pick (the changes introduced by some existing commits)

     ```
         git cherry-pick ec59ab844cf504e462f011c8cc7e5667ebb2e9c7
     ```
   - Or by cherry-picking the range of commits by:

     - First checking the right changes before merging them:

       ```
       git diff 5216b24822ea1c48069f648449997879bb49c070..4c3e23f529b581c3cbe95350e84e66e3cb05704f
       ```
     - First checking the right changes before merging them:

       ```
       git cherry-pick 5216b24822ea1c48069f648449997879bb49c070..4c3e23f529b581c3cbe95350e84e66e3cb05704f
       ```

       where this is the range of the correct commits which you've committed (excluding wrongly committed merge).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest of the simplest chance, much simpler than anything said here:

Remove your local branch (local, not remote) and pull it again. This way you'll undo the changes on your master branch and anyone will be affected by the change you don't want to push. Start it over.

Answer (score 1):

If you committed the merge:

```
git reset HEAD~1
# Make sure what you are reverting is in fact the merge files
git add .
git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `git stash`
2. `git branch -d the_local_branch`
3. `git checkout -t <name of remote>`
4. `git stash apply`

This worked for me..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you notice that you need to revert immediately after the merge and you haven't done anything else after the merge attempt, you can just issue this command:
`git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`.

Essentially, your merge `sha` will be pointing to `HEAD@{0}` if nothing else was committed after the merge and so `HEAD@{1}` will be the previous point before the merge.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you will want to reset your branch with `git reset --hard <branch_name>`. If you want to save your changes before reseting them be sure to create a new branch and `git checkout <branch_name>`.

You can reset the state to a specific commit with `git reset --hard <commit_id>` as well.

If the changes have been pushed you can use `git revert <branch_name>` instead. Be sure to check out how to use [git revert and git checkout](https://kolosek.com/git-reset-revert-and-checkout/) in other scenarios as well.

Answer (score -13):

You can use the git-reset command.

> git-reset - Reset current HEAD to the
>
> specified state. git reset [--mixed |
>
> --soft | --hard | --merge] [-q] [] git reset [-q] []
>
> [--] … git reset --patch
>
> [] [--] […]

[GIT-Reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Comment: I tried `git reset`, `git reset --merge`, and `git reset --hard`, but I still end up with the same message about being 5 commits ahead of origin/master.