# Undoing a git merge

Tags: git, merge

I'm not that experienced with Git and now I have a big problem falling into my lap.

Here's how my current branch look like:

```
feature       /---F1-----F2----\
             /                  \
master -----M0-----M1-----M2-----M3-----M4
             \                        /
bugfix        \--B1-----B2-----------/
```

**The situation:**

Someone did a very bad thing and pushed a really bad merge (M3). I only noticed the bad merge when our models (not source code) wouldn't load after I merged B1 and B2 into M4. Luckily, I haven't pushed M4 yet.

**The problem:**

How do I set things right again? I want M0, M1, M2, F1, F2, B1, and B2. But I don't want M3 and M4 (since M4 is obviously broken). If I *have* to abandon changes, then F1 and F2 can be sacrificed :)

I looked at `git revert` but I'm not confident that I fully understand how it works. So... I'm really hoping for help on how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So to clarify, what you want is this, right?

```
feature       /---F1-----F2
             /                 
master -----M0-----M1-----M2
             \            
bugfix        \--B1-----B2
```

Make sure that the `HEAD`s `feature` and `bugfix` are still on `F2` and `B2` respectively.

**Edit**: if `feature` and `bugfix` are no branches, make them branches (stash your work if it is uncommited):

```
git checkout F2
git branch feature
git checkout B2
git branch bugfix
```

**Edit end**

Then reset the master to M2:

```
git checkout master
git reset M2 --hard
```

(reset will make you lose your local changes, stash them if you don't want that.)

`M3` and `M4` are not destroyed right away, but will be eventually. They should not show up in `git log` or gitk.

Then it's time to merge `feature` and make a `M3'` that is correct.

Comment: Yes, sort of, but "feature", "master", and "bugfix" are not actually branches, I suspect that's what's confusing. That is, 3 ppl committed to their own changes of the master branch. One guy did a bad merge and pushed. I pulled the bad merge. Now I want a way to exclude the bad merge while still keeping all the individual changes...

Comment: So `feature` and `bugfix` are no branches? Surely the author of `feature` has a branch in his own repo. What you should do is to reset your master to M2, and ask the author of `feature` to do the same (but make sure he does not lose the branch `feature`) and redo the merge, correctly this time. See my update if you want to do that yourself.

Comment: Do you really have a repo without a `master` branch?

Comment: We do have a `master` branch. Ok, now I see what you mean about getting the other guy to reset this branch. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't push (publish) the merge commits yet, use git reset. E.g. on the master branch, assuming your working tree is clean, do git reset --hard .

More info:
[Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/git-undo-a-merge)

If you did publish your changes you might want to consider making a revert commit instead. More info here:
http://progit.org/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html