# Revert a Pull Request on master after other commits

Tags: git

Similar to this [Undo a merge by pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481575/undo-a-merge-by-pull-request) but master already has many many commits ahead of that pull request. What would be a way to undo an old pull request correctly? Does cherry picking work in this case somehow?

Note: This is all pushed and not local.

Comment: this is the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481575/undo-a-merge-by-pull-request#answer-16298304

Comment: Totally missed that. How does that handle new commits that were on the same files as in the pull request?

Comment: as long as they don't modify the same lines, any new commits will remain intact.  If you've touched any of the same lines, you'll have to fix it manually.