# Github: Changes ignored after revert (git cherrypick, git rebase)

Tags: git, github

Lets say I have two branches `A` and `B`

```
(A)--------(A+B)--------------(A+B+R)
 \        / merge   \ revert  /
  \      /           \       /
 (B)----(B+)         (R)----
```

First, I merged branch `B` to `A`,
Then I reverted the merge request with GitHub's revert feature.

Now when I fix some code on branch `B` and need to merge to `A` again, **almost all** changes (except the new one that I fix) are ignored. How can I get the changes again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read here how to "reset" your changes
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)

Once you have the code you want it push it again to the repository. Since you did a revert and not reset you can simply push the code without any problem.

If you have done a `reset` and you wish to update the remote branch you will have to `force` push with the `git push -f origin master` and this will result in a rebase which will affect all your co workers as well.

---

> How can i get the changes again?

#### `git cherry-pick`

The easiest way is simply to do a `git cherry-pick` to pick the desired commit back to your branch again.

```
# Find out the range of commits you wish to re-add to your branch.
# then use cherry-pick to add them back to the branch

git cherry-pick start..end

# If you wish to include the start commit as well add the ^
# This will result in a cherry-pick of the start commit included as well 
git cherry-pick start^..end
```

---

#### `git rebase --onto` (Carefull = rebase)

```
# reset it to the start commit
git reset --hard start

# rebase every commit after b and transplant it onto a
git rebase --onto commit1 commit2 commit3 ... commitN
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

You need to revert the revert, i.e. revert the commit that your previous revert created.

The reason for this is that a merge really does 2 things: it changes the file contents to reflect the merge, and also creates a commit with 2 parents to tell git what was merged. When you revert, it undoes the first thing, but not the second. So when you try to re-do the merge, git has no idea that you reverted the previous merge, so it ignores everything before then.

Comment: After reading tons of answers, urs made it super simple to know why this is happening, hence how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: This explains my misery 3 years back! what is the resolution though? I had a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/q/49386213/1298918

Comment: @antnewbee I posted an answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

One more option how to resolve the case when you need to merge a branch that was previously merged and reverted, is - switch to that feature branch and squash commits (this is needed to generate new commit hash), you can do this by `git reset --soft HEAD~2` (2 is total number of commits on that branch) after this, you can push your changes to feature branch by `git push` (you may need either [the `--force` or `--force-with-lease` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823692/git-push-force-with-lease-vs-force)).
Now when you try to create merge request you will see that all changes are there and git sees it as a new changes (because of **new commit hash**)

Answer (score 0):

If you reverted your changes on a branch then you want to do some modifications and push those changes again; a handful thing to do might  revert your revert.

Let's assume;

- you have working branch name `working-branch` and you did your changes on that.
- you merged this to another branch; let's say `master`
- figured out a problem and reverted those changes from `master`.
- you used the current `working-branch` or created a new branch from it but git is not detecting your all changes, it only detects your new changes added on after merging.

instead of handling all cherry-pick/rebase stuff you can simply do:

- `git checkout master` (first get master)
- `git pull origin master` (get the latest changes)
- `git checkout -b working-branch-v2` (create another branch)
- `git revert <revert_commit_hash_on_master>` (revert your revert on that)

Eventually you'll end up with a brand new branch with all reverted changes. Now you can do your fixes and push this as a new branch. Then you'll able to merge into master again.