# git pull from wrong remote branch

Tags: git, branch, remote-branch

My origin has a `fixes` and a `fixes_v3` branch.  My client has just `fixes`.  I do a `git pull git+ssh:/.../mygitrepo` and suddenly on my client I have all the `fixes_v3` code in the `fixes` branch.  Why on earth did this happen?  Now I try `git pull ... mygitrepo fixes` and it just tells me it's up to date.

`git remote show origin` gives this:

```
HEAD branch: fixes
Local refs configured for 'git push':
  fixes  pushes to fixes  (fast-forwardable)
  master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, probably some bad setting, but I have one advice. [Don't `git pull`](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/). Use `git fetch` and `git merge` in two steps so you can see what you are merging with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your branches are tracking the false remotes. Do a `git remote show origin` to see which branch remote branch `fixes` merges. It probably will say something like

```
fixes merges with remote fixes_v3
```

Adjust this accordingly after undoing your last merge.

Comment: @djechlin, your edit shows configuration for `git push`, not `git pull`

Comment: @djechlin This is your issue. Your repos are not configured for `pull`. `git pull repo` is equivalent to `git fetch && git merge FETCH_HEAD` where `FETCH_HEAD` is the alphabetically first ref. The lesson here is probably, that you shouldn't pull without configuring for it.

Comment: Fair lesson.  Basically `git fetch` is better functionality until you know what you're doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**The quick fix?**

Undo all local commits.  E.g.

Select branch for undo

```
git branch fixes
```

Remove local commits

```
git reset --hard origin/fixes
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343267/939250)

**How did the topic branch get messed up?**

In my case, I'd done a pull without naming the destination:

```
git pull origin cifs_support
```

Since there was no local `cifs_support` branch,  the commits from `origin/cifs_support` were added to `master`.

**Are you safe?**

No.  Check your config using the advice in the accepted answer:  use `git remote show origin` to see which branches are affected by `git pull` and `git push`.  If branch tracking is wrong, fix it ASAP.