# git undo pushed merge to restore separate branches

Tags: git, merge, branch

First, I have to apologise - there are quite a number of 'how to undo a merge' questions on SO, but I'm so new at git that I really don't understand how to adapt the solutions them to my situation (though I'm sure they can be).

I have two branches, `versionA` and `versionB`. I made some changes in `versionA` and merged them into `versionB`, which is fine because the changes made in `versionA` are forwards compatible. Then, I think I must have accidentally merged `versionB` back into `versionA`, which is not fine because `versionB` is *not* backwards-compatible to `versionA`.

How can I undo this?

To make things clearer, this is what I've done:

```
versionA C--C--C--C'--M2
          \          /
           \        /
versionB C--M--C--C*

M: merged versionA into versionB. this is fine.
M2: accidentally merged versionB back into versionA
```

This is what  I want:

```
versionA C--C--C--C'
          \         
           \       
versionB C--M--C--C*
```

If I were on Mercurial I'd do `hg rollback` and all would be fine, or I'd `hg update C'` and make future commits off there for the `versionA` branch, although this would leave `M2` as a dead dangling head (hence I'd prefer the `rollback` method).

What is the git way to scrub that last commit `M2` from the `versionA` branch? (All changes have been pushed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the commit of the merge.

To find the merge commit try:
`git log versionA ^versionB --ancestry-path --merges`

The needed commit is the very last commit.

git revert -m 1 commit_hash

But please read up on Linus' write up: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

Also see: [Which commit hash to undo a pushed merge using git-revert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563346/to-undo-a-pushed-merge-using-git-revert-how-can-i-identify-the-right-commit-has)

Comment: Thanks! Could I request some further explanation? What would my history look like with the first option? `M2` is a dangling head and further commits to `versionA` all come off `C'`? (i.e. my history for `versionA` looks like a single continuous line with one little (dead) leaf `M2` hanging off it?) Also, could you explain what `git reset HEAD^ --hard` does? I a look at `git help reset` but it does not explain what the `^` after `HEAD` means (although it uses it in the examples). I'm guessing it means "the commit prior to `HEAD`"?

Comment: Finally, if I do the second version (scrubbing the history), what will happen if someone else already has pulled `M2` into their history? And similarly, if a future person pulls the repository will they see `M2` at all?

Comment: To answer the first couple of questions - I found the explanation for `HEAD^` in `git help revisions`. And based off `git help revert`, I think my new `versionA` history will be `C--C--C--C'--M2--M2'`, where `M2'` says "reverted changes of M2". The other questions (will the `reset HEAD^ --hard` screw over anyone who has already checked out `M2`) still stand.

Comment: You better do this before anybody has fetched the repo, or people might not like you. I also just realized it's a merge that want to revert, that's a bit more complicated. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update - but isn't the commit of the merge `M2`? (or do you mean `C'`?) Also, your command does not return anything at all.

Comment: Thanks. I read Linus' explanation and it appears that the "commit of the merge" is `M2` (which I know). Also, I do not need to revert the revert as Linus suggests, because `versionB` is *never* supposed to be merged into `versionA`, since `versionB` is not backwards compatible to `versionA` (as stated in the question). Hence I just need to do a single revert. cheers!