# Revert merge Git-Flow

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using SourceTree and Git-Flow pattern. Now I have prepared a release for my beta-testers to test so I created a new `release/v1.0.1` branch. But my mind slipped and I decided to finish (merge into `develop` and `master` and tag) the release even though I haven't even sent out the release to my testers. So I would like to have the release branch open up again if my testers finds any bugs I can fix these bugs in the release branch and then when all bugs are fixed I can finish the release.

So how can I easily with SourceTree preferably (or using git commands) revert back to the state when I had the `release/v1.0.1` branch?

Attached screendump from SourceTree:

[image]

**EDIT:** Okay I did the `git reset --hard HEAD~2` on `develop` (HEAD~2) because I had tested manually checking out. But now when I checkout `master` and do a `git reflog` it seems to me that I should do a reset on HEAD~6

```
Peters-MacBook-Pro:Remessage peterwarbo$ git reflog
f7663b1 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from develop to master
3d132da HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD~2
2f1c753 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to develop
f7663b1 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from develop to master
2f1c753 HEAD@{4}: merge release/v1.0.1: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
4332fe4 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from master to develop
f7663b1 HEAD@{6}: merge release/v1.0.1: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
fe323ef HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from release/v1.0.1 to master
28a63ea HEAD@{8}: commit: Bumped version number to 1.0.1
```

But when I do that I get this "error":

```
Peters-MacBook-Pro:Project peterwarbo$ git reset --hard HEAD~6
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~6': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

**EDIT 2:** New image to illustrate fuckup.

[image]

**EDIT 3:** Attached new image to illustrate the current state now after issuing the git commands in user1615903´s answer. Why does it say that develop is 2 behind? And why is there a merge from `release/v1.0.1` to master even though I did a reset to master to the initial commit (`fe323ef`)?

[image]

Comment: So basically you just need to remove the last commit in master and in develop, and set 28a63ea as "release/v1.0.1" again?

Comment: I believe so? I also need to remove the merge that was done to `master` and `develop`

Comment: The tag should be removed as well. Basically I just want to go back in time to the state when I had created the `release/v1.0.1` branch and made that commit to bump the version number.

Comment: `HEAD~6` (6 commits back from HEAD) is not the same as `HEAD@{6}` (6 git operations ago)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is quite easy. Things you will need to do are:

- Reset develop branch to the commit it was before merge
- Reset master branch to the commit it was before merge
- Have the release branch point to the correct commit again
- Remove the tag
- Push the fixed commits to remote

So to do steps 1 and 2:

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard 4332fe4

git checkout master
git reset --hard <SHA of the commit the master was before the merge>
```

Then to "recreate" the release branch:

```
git checkout -b "release/v1.0.1" 28a63ea
```

And finally to remove the tag:

```
git tag -d v1.0.1
```

More information about undoing a merge in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge)

After that, if the changes were already pushed, you need to use the -f switch to override changes in remote:

```
git push -f
```

And to delete the tag from the remote:

```
git push --delete origin v1.0.1
```

Comment: I tried what you recommended but I seem to be stuck now? See my updated question please.

Comment: So, you did reset with HEAD~2? That means you moved the branch tip two commits behind, and now you are trying to move it 6 more commits behind? Please include a new picture from SourceTree, it really helps to illustrate this.

Comment: So I foobared? Can I undo that? (I have my repository mirrored at Bitbucket fortunately) I'm uploading new picture now.

Comment: Edited my answer so that it refers to commit SHA's instead of HEAD-something. Don't worry, it's really difficult to PERMANENTLY delete things in git.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28438/discussion-between-user1615903-and-peter-warbo)