# Using git flow, how would I revert back to a previous release?

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

I'm using git flow for my projects. When a release has been merged into the master branch it is tagged with the release version (e.g. 1.2.0) and deployed to my production servers.

Now I want to **quickly revert to the previous release tag** (e.g. 1.1.0) as the deployment should not have happened.

Elaboration:

- I merge the 1.2.0 release branch into the master branch.
- I tag the master branch with 1.2.0.
- I push my local repo to the origin.
- I conclude that I released too early.
- I want to revert back to the state of master where it was tagged as 1.1.0.
- I want the master @ origin to revert back to the 1.1.0 state as well.

[image]

**How would I do this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081260/revert-merge-git-flow/

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I read that post but it doesn't answer my question. They are talking about resetting the dev brnach. I don't want that. My master branch is tagged with releases. I just want to fall back to a previous tag in my master branch.

Comment: `git checkout v1.1.0` would take you back to the previous release - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I can checkout the master branch, but that's not enough. How would I let the origin know that I want this commit to be the 'active' one?

Comment: By doing the reset for the master branch and then doing `git push -f` just as described in the link I provided

Comment: But I would lose the 1.2.0 commit, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes you would. Is that not what you wanted? _deployment should not have happened_ you said in your question. Also, what do you mean by _letting the origin know that I want this commit to be the 'active' one_? Origin is a bare repository, there's no workspace, so there's no checked out branch there. Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll update the question.

Comment: @user1615903: would he really LOSE the commit, or would the commit be just detached (and i.e. stay visible in reflog and be ready to be reattached and further worked upon)?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl It would be detached yes, until it gets garbage collected, so he would eventually lose the commit.

Comment: @Kriem where is that screenshot coming from? Is it a visualization tool or did you create it manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the history, but undo the changes the 1.2.0 release did. Use [git-revert](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) to create a new commit that reverts everything 1.2.0 did:

```
git checkout master
git revert HEAD
```

Comment: Do I lose the 1.2.0 tag? In other words, do I lose the point in history where I created the 1.2.0 tag at the master branch?

Comment: No. This will keep everything in place - it adds a new commit after 1.2.0 tag.

Comment: @Kriem Tags are separate pointers not related to branches (which are just pointers themselves). So changing a branch will not change tags.

Comment: @poke - I'm afraid I don't really understand.

Comment: I can't revert: `Commit ... is a merge but no -m option was given.`

Comment: @Kriem Branches and tags are just pointers or labels for commit objects (the things with that hash, e.g. 17813ace…). When you commit, the branch pointer moves to the new commit object, so branches are somewhat “dynamic” pointers. Tags are such pointers as well, but usually you would not want them to move; they are meant to stay the way they are forever (so you have an always valid reference to the *same* version). Now just because you move a branch, i.e. make it point to something else, a tag that points to something won’t change. They are completely unrelated in that aspect.

Comment: @poke I'm beginning to understand. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Pretty old stuff here, but I find the accepted answer very misleading. In my opinion code versioning and release management are two orthogonal problems. You should be able to deploy any version to production at any time without messing with your branches.

Comment: @Ricovitch the question is specifically about the "git flow" workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove your last commit and its history, you must use git commands:

```
(git checkout develop)
git reset HEAD^ --hard
git push origin -f

git checkout master
git reset HEAD^ --hard
git push origin -f
```

This remove the last commit in master and develop and their history, including the tags.