# Git remove remote merge and branch

Tags: git

I have been working on my develop branch. I checked out branch 'branch-xxx', commit my changes and then merged the branch on develop, only to find out that this piece of code is buggy!

How can I undo the merge and remove the branch?

I checked out [Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge)
But even though it seems I am indeed moving to the previous commit, I can't figure out how to push this to the remote.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you are done with reverting the merge, but need help pushing the changes to the remote? Then a `git push --force origin branch_name` can help you. (note that this might cause trouble if others checked out your branch)

Comment: I did "git reset --hard HEAD~1 ", in this way going back on the last commit before mine. Should I do that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply reset your develop branch to state before merge. Then delete your 'branch-xxx'.

Comment: So I should do git reset --hard HEAD~1 and then git push origin :branch-xxx?

Comment: If your develop branch had no other commits and if you pushed branch-xxx to remote - yes. If you have also pushed your develop branch to public server you'll also need `git push -f origin develop` but actually this makes things a bit worse - and you should use `git revert` instead.

Comment: There is no other commits after mine. All the changes are pushed to the remote develop. I am a bit cautious before actually doing something in the remove.