# Git: How to avoid conflicts on merging a feature branch after a previous merge revert

Tags: git, conflict, git-merge, git-revert, feature-branch

In our repository we develop features based on feature branches. Lately I integrated a feature `feature/myfeature` into `master`:

```
git merge --no-ff feature/myfeature
```

After this merge some more development happened until it turned out, that this feature was faulty and blocked integration so I decided to revert this merge. Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/6217372/1237653 I choosed the only option to revert the merge without breaking the history:

```
git revert -m 1 commit_hash
```

Meanwhile even more development on `master`has happened as well as the author has added fixup commits. Now I want to go for a second run to integrate/merge the feature. Unfortunately now I get dozen of conflicts, because the first apply & revert touches the very same lines of code as it would the second try.

```
git merge --no-ff feature/myfeature
<pointless conflicts all over>
```

**How can I reapply my previously reverted feature-branch without those pointless conflicts?**

I tried `-s recursive -Xrenormalize` without luck. Rebase would cause the same conflicts, too.

Comment: As a "workaround" I destroyed the history of a feature-branch by manually cherry-picking all its commits into a new branch overwriting the old one. Feels bad & ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of merging a second time the branch you reverted, you should revert the revert commit.  I mean literally,

```
git revert <sha1>
```

where `sha1` is the commit made by your earlier `git revert`.

Comment: Thanks! I think this solution has some usability flaws, because after that I have to reapply/merge the feature branch a second time to catch the remaining changes. And if that fails again, then everything quadrupels...