# Is it possible to merge renames in git if changes occur in a future commit than the rename?

Tags: git, rename, branching-and-merging

I have a bit of an odd issue with a repo. I have a branch by another dev, called other, and I just merged into master some refactors that involved renaming a bunch of files.

```
         [other]      /->[normal commits]-----------------\
                     /                                     \
[master] (old)->(old)->---------->[potential file changes]--->[potentially difficultmerge due to potential file changes]
                               /
[otherbranch] [massive rename]/
```

Can I change their contents in a later commit (actually java package identification) before merging other without having to do nasty resolution of these renames? The files in question are modified in `other` quite a bit.

Edit: Git-merge with recursive and patience should be able to pick up the merge nicely if it's not renamed, so would the same logic apply to renames?

Comment: Why don't you just revert your merge, merge 'other' and then merge your branch again?

Comment: @the.malkolm You're talking about reverting the merge of the renames, merging `other`, and remerging the renames afterward? It seems like it should work.. Can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just revert 'rename' merge, merge 'other' and then merge 'rename' again? Not the perfect solution but should work right here and right now.

Take a look here to figure out how to **correctly** revert a merge [Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge)