# Merge that can be undone after developing on top of it

Tags: git

I have a branch on my local machine that has a complex history going back several months with many commits and merges with master.

I now want to merge this branch into master, deploy it, but if necessary in the future be able to do a single revert to undo the merge on to master.  For example I merge today, but then a week later (after other commits for other features have been done) we discover we have to undo this merge.

Is it as simple as doing a revert using the sha from the merge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes doing a `git revert` on the merge commit should reverse the effects of the merge.

If you wait a week you may of course have to resolve conflicts with other changes that have occurred. After resolving them you can `git revert --continue`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should revise your workflow and only use master for what is deployed. Google "branch per feature" You should find my post.