# "git reset xxx" command on windows does not perform the same action as linux?

Tags: windows, git, pull, git-reset

At the HEAD version, I have a mistake that pull another branch when I on master branch so that some new files or directories had been merged into master branch from another. I realize this is a very big mistake. So I use "git reset xxx" to restore into xxx commit version. However, after done command, I really back to xxx commit version and those new files or directories also are there. What's wrong with this action? Whether I take a wrong command? I just want to back to a clean old commit version without any changes by wrong pull action. Thx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo a Git merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge)

Comment: Sorry, but it can not fix my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get back to an old commit , discarding all changes:

```
git reset --hard commit-id
```

Without the `--hard` switch you are doing a *mixed reset* which means that the changes will still be retained in your working set. The `--hard` switch gets rid of those too.

If you also want to remove any untracked files then:

```
git clean -f
```

Comment: "git clean -f -d" works fine, thanks. What's more, why I use "git reset xxx --hard" on windows, the tracked new files or directories in HEAD version change into untracked status in xxx version?

Comment: @xohozu because the right syntax is `git reset --hard xxx`, not `git reset xxx --hard`.

Comment: @VonC There's no difference between `git reset --hard xxx` and `git reset xxx --hard`.  In general, Git allows command line options to show up before or after arguments.  Are you seeing a different behavior?

Comment: @jszakmeister no, you are right. I had it mixed up with the `<path>` parameter.

Comment: @xohozu that doesn't happen, new tracked files would be deleted when you reset. If it appears that new untracked files appear , it may be because you are resetting over a change to the .gitignore file

Comment: @matt-mcnabb you means that windows platform also performs same action, i will check it next time. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
git reset --hard xxxx
```

That would reset the working tree too, in addition of the index.

[image: http://git-scm.com/images/reset/reset-hard.png]

(From "[Reset Demystified](http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html)")

Resetting the index only wouldn't get rid of the local modifications done to your working tree.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I experienced the same issue, `git reset --hard xxxx` does not work in Windows git terminal.

This was my response from git terminal:

> $ git reset --hard XXXX fatal: ambiguous argument 'XXXX': unknown
> revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths
> from revisions, like this: 'git  [...] --
> [...]'

Comment: I meant xxx as a placeholder, which is supposed to be replaced with the commit id you want to reset to.