# git revert <hash> not allowed due to a merge but no -m option was given

Tags: git, github, revert, git-revert

I am trying to revert to a certain 'hash' number in git, by using the 'revert' command.

I am using the following command:

```
git revert c14609d74eec3ccebafc73fa875ec58445471765
```

But, I am getting the following returned:

> error: Commit c14609d74eec3ccebafc73fa875ec58445471765 is a merge but no -m option was given.
> fatal: revert failed

What is happening & what should be done to resolve this?

---

I want to revert back to this certain commit (`c14609d74eec3ccebafc73fa875ec58445471765`) that I see when running `git log`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo a Git merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You are trying to revert a merge commit, and git doesn't know which parent to revert to. The `-m` allows us to choose which parent to choose. See the merge commit and note down which parent you want to go to. The parent information can be seen in `git log`, for example:

> commit d02ee0f2179def10277f30c71c5d6f59ded3c595
>
> Merge: dd3a24c 2462a52

and run:

```
git revert <hash> -m 1
```

where `1` indicates parent number 1 (dd3a24c).

If you are trying to revert *to* that commit, do:

```
git reset --hard <hash>
```

Understand the difference between `git revert` and `git reset` from the docs and decide which one you want. `git revert` is the safer option, but doesn't really do what you want. It just reverts the changes of a (set of) commit. `git reset` makes you move to a particular commit in history, and will rewrite your history.

Comment: manojlds, what was the full `git log` command that you ran to see the parent?

Comment: How do you determine which parent is which? i.e. How do I know to enter the number `1` v.s. `2` or something else?

Comment: I originally merged a dev branch into `master`. When reverting the commit I used `1` as the value of `-m` which did the trick

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs I found this helpful answer to "How do you determine which parent is which?" [https://blog.experteer.engineering/what-are-parents-on-git-merge-commits.html](https://blog.experteer.engineering/what-are-parents-on-git-merge-commits.html)

Answer (score 4):

> I want to revert back to ...

Then you don't want `git revert`, at least not like this. `git revert` is for reverting the specific changes made in that commit. What you're looking for is to revert or undo all the changes made *after* that commit.

`git reset` is the command to use here.

`git reset --hard c14609d74eec3ccebafc73fa875ec58445471765` completely resets your branch, index and work tree to that specific commit.

Note that the usual precautions apply: if anyone else has fetched later commits already, removing them from the history like this complicates matters for them. If you instead want to create a new commit, which simply restores the state to that of commit c14609d74eec3ccebafc73fa875ec58445471765, you can use `git rm` and `git checkout`:

```
git rm -r .
git checkout c14609d74eec3ccebafc73fa875ec58445471765 .
```

(The `rm` is needed to make sure newly added files also get removed.)
This lets you then create a new commit, on top of your local history, which undoes every change since c14609d74eec3ccebafc73fa875ec58445471765.