# Remove a merge from master

Tags: git, merge

I had a branch that I merged into master.  Then we've merged other things into master after that.  So we now have this state in master

```
------------------------------
stuff added to master recently
------------------------------
my branch merged into master
------------------------------
old stuff in master
------------------------------
```

I want to remove my merge from master and leave all else intact so that I get the following state in master

```
------------------------------
stuff added to master recently
------------------------------
old stuff in master
------------------------------
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a rebase interactive on `master`, and use that interactive rebase session to drop the commits you don't want anymore ([`git rebase -i`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)).

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i <SHA1 old stuff in master>
```

Note that it will change the master history, which would lead to a `git push --force` if you already pushed master to a remote repo. And that could be inconvenient for others having already pulled from that same remote repo.

If you had already pushed master, then a [`git revert -m 1`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) would be easier to push as well: See "[Undo a Git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6217372/6309)". That will create a new commit (cancelling the merge one)