# Git - how to roll back after a mistakenly "merge"

Tags: git, merge

I mistakenly merged one branch (`a`) to branch(`b`), now the files in `a` got deleted.

I don't have any tag for branch `a`, and made several commits previously.

How to roll back or back the stage before the merge was made, so I can have my files back?

I tried: `git reset --soft HEAD~3`
Seems it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo a Git merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge)

Comment: reset soft change only information about commits. Please try to use git reset --hard  instead. It will rollback also files.

Comment: If you merged branch A into branch B, that means only B was modified. You make it sound like you care about the files in branch A, so what's the problem here?

Comment: Kamil, Nick,  by using hard,  I won't have much risk to lose more, right?

Comment: You can only lose uncommited data. Do a backup anyway. `git reset --hard` will change commit history, but old HEAD will be accessible with `git reflog`.

Comment: Thanks, please make some comment, then I can give point to you, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
A --- B --- C - branch_a
 \           \
  --D--- E ---F - branch_b
```

`branch_a` was merged to `branch_b`, but the content of `branch_a` is unchanged. You can do `git checkout branch_a` and the files on your file system will be as they were on `branch_a` before the merge.

---

If the merge of `branch_a` to `branch_b` (commit `F`) was wrong, you can roll it back, and set `branch_b` to where it was before the merge. `git reset` is the command of choice for moving `HEAD`s (branches) around:

```
git checkout branch_b
git reset <SHA_1 of commit E> # --hard would update your local files as well, if you wish
```

resulting in:

```
A --- B --- C - branch_a
 \           
  --D--- E - branch_b
```

Commit `F` has disappeared (you could still find it, at least for a while, but that is more advanced).