# How to remove a branch merged with develop in bitbucket git?

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisegit

This is a question on Bitbucket/git. Let's say you have created a feature branch from develop branch. Let me call the branch `feature/newBranchA`.

I did git pull request, and merged it to develop branch.

However, now I want to get rid of the commits from the `newBranchA`, aka I want develop to remove the commit.

I realize we can do a git reset hard. However, is it possible to do such from Bitbucket from the GUI interface? Is it possible to do similar from TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove commits coming from a merged branch, there is a brilliant answer here: [Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge)

It is not possible to undo a merge in Bitbucket's interface, and as far as I know Tortoise does not support that either.

Comment: No. Actually newBranchA contained work that client almost at end of project decided not to include and discard forever. It has already been merged to develop and work in develop was approved. . So yeah I understand the concept of branching. I am asking what is the best way to remove the merged code in develop that came from newBranchA without having to cheery pick

Comment: Ah, okay. It seems I did not understand your question before. So you want to remove the merged commits that come from newBranchA from the master branch?

Comment: I edited my answer now that I understand your question better. Let me know if I still got it wrong.