# Keep getting 'Partial Merge Commit' Dialog

Tags: git, phpstorm, bitbucket

I am trying to commit some changed files. There are several, but I only want to commit a few from a specific folder.

Everytime I attempt to commit, I get a Dialog box with a popup that says **Partial Merge Commit**.

It also has the message *Partial commit during a merge is not allowed. The following files are not included in commit. Perform commit with all files included*

I don't want to commit all the files, just the batch I am working on currently. Does anyone know how to get pass this? I may have made a mistake with a menu somewhere, but searching settings isn't giving me anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Partial commit during a merge is not allowed.

You're in the middle of a merge process. You cannot commit just some files. A merge needs all files to be commited.

#### If you want to stop the merge

**Option 1.**

```
git stash save
git merge --abort
```

**Option 2.** If you really need to save your changes.

```
git add --all
git commit
```

Now the merge is done and you've got your changes saved. Now [undo the merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge), and retrieve the needed changed from your merge commit to where you need them.

#### If you want to continue.

> The following files are not included in commit.

The list of files are not included yet.

> Perform commit with all files included

Add them and make a commit. The merge will then be completed. Make sure that you've resolved the merge conflicts before.

```
git add --all
git commit -m'message'
```

Comment: I understand this, but how do I get out of the merge? I haven't purposely initiated it.