# Git refer to commit that was merged into the current branch

Tags: git, github

This is the state of my git repo(u1 means me and u2 is someone else)

```
C1(U1)->C2(U2)->C3(U2)->C4(U2)->C5(U2)->C6(U2)->C7(U2)->C8(U2)->C9(U2)->C10(U1)
```

So only C1 is my commit and C10 is actually a conflict merge commit(when I pulled changes from forked repo).

My current HEAD is at C10. I want it to be at C9.

When I do 
`git reset --hard HEAD~1`
I see that it actually reverts to C1(my last commit in history), which is not overall last commit.

How do I revert to C9?

Comment: use `git log` to check the hash of C9 and use `git reset --hard <hash>`? :)

Comment: @KevinGuan sure. But is it expected behavior that git reset --hard HEAD~1 reverts to MY last commit(and not overall last commit?)

Comment: Hum, let me check the document.

Comment: OK, I find another question like your question, take a look : [undo-a-git-merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write `git reset --hard HEAD^2` , which means to access the second parent of the merge commit (which is the one of U2)

See git-revisions

```
git help revisions
```

> ~, e.g. master~3
>
> A suffix ~ to a revision parameter means the commit object that is the `<n>`th generation
>       ancestor of the named commit object, **following only the first parents**. I.e.  `<rev>~3` is
>       equivalent to `<rev>^^^` which is equivalent to `<rev>^1^1^1`. See below for an illustration of the
>       usage of this form.

The first parents are, in case of a merge request, the commit that a branch was merged into (here you merged C9 into C1), so C1 is the first parent, and C9 the second parent.

You can access to the `nth` parent of a commit with `commit^n`

So if you do

```
git reset --hard HEAD^2
```

it should work

Additional info about the `^` notation :

> `<rev>`^, e.g. HEAD^, v1.5.1^0
>
> A suffix ^ to a revision parameter means the first parent of that commit object.  ^`<n>` means
>       the `<n>`th parent (i.e.  `<rev>`^ is equivalent to `<rev>`^1). As a special rule, `<rev>`^0 means the 
>       commit itself and is used when `<rev>` is the object name of a tag object that refers to a commit
>       object.

Comment: Does not work. HEAD^2 rollbacks to MY second last commit(i.e. the commit before C1). I want it to be at C9 (which is overall parent of C10)

Comment: Are you sure you use `^` and  not `~` ? Can you send a screenshot of `gitk` ? It works fine for me here : http://i.imgur.com/sUcT6TF.png?1 git reset --hard HEAD^2 goes correctly to the "fix issue" commit

Comment: Yes you are right. I was using ~ instead of ^. However that again led me to C9, but I saw that commit C1 (and one before it was lost as I did not push it to remote). I ended up using HEAD~1 and then pulling the code from remote and merging again.