# To take master one step back (GIT)

Tags: git

Actually, I want take origin/master origin/head comes one step back on "ce424fc - team split for nba and player injuries".

After that I push origin/master origin/head it wont ask me to take pull of 9a29db2.

My history graph looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RqLm.png).

Comment: your question is not clear... what does `git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph` give you (for the last commits)? And what would you like it to be?

Comment: do you mean you want to **undo** the merge?

Comment: both locally and on remote, or only on the remote?

Comment: Yes. I want to do undo the merge. What to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo a Git merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge)

Comment: look in the related commit; something like git reset --hard and then git push -f

Answer (score 0):

The remote branch has new commits that you dont have in you local branch.

You have to pull the origin to your local repository to get those changes.

```
# update your local repository
git fetch --all --prune

# merge the changes to your local master
git pull origin master
```

Now you are up to date with the server + your changes are merged into your local branch.

Comment: I want take origin/master origin/head comes one step back on "ce424fc - team split for nba and player injuries" not on  9a29db2 hash code. Please help me.

Comment: Read this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revet-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716