# Changing the starting commit of a new git branch

Tags: git, branch, commit

I forgot to do a `pull` before creating a new branch. I did not recognize that, did the work and a finishing `merge`. Now I see that the starting point of the new (and now merged) branch is wrong as it is too far in the past.

Is it possible to correct that?

Comment: Create a new branch from the right point, then cherry-pick your commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the history consists of two branches - `master` & `topic`. `topic` is the branch you created from master without doing a `git pull`.

```
git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD  // Undo git-merge
git checkout master
git pull
git rebase master topic  // Replay commits of topic on new master
```

After this you can proceed with merge (if required).

---

For more detail on undo git-merge, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet)