# How to reset to the state before a merge was committed?

Tags: git, git-merge

I've resolved some conflicts and committed a merge. Is it possible to restore exactly the merge state that was before running `git commit`, not changing the index or the working tree? For regular single-parent commits, the command which does this is `git reset --soft HEAD^`, but for merge commits it doesn't work as expected, because there is no single parent to reset to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet)

Comment: Nope, I'm asking about something similar to `reset --soft`

Comment: Can you state your goal more precisely? It sounds like you fixed all the conflicts and committed, but realized you wanted to perform more changes?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to get back to the merge state

Comment: It's not clear what precisely you're looking to do - what "merge state"? What you seem to be describing is the "merge conflict" state which has everything to do with the working tree and nothing to do with commits.

Comment: This is a great resource straight from Github: [How to undo \(almost\) anything with Git](https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is supported, but you can fake it by doing `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}` and then writing the commit id that you were merging to `.git/MERGE_HEAD`.

You'll lose the commit message, though ("Merge commit 'cafebab' into HEAD").

Answer (score 2):

You have a `commit-sha for your merge state`. Find the commit by `git log` or, `git reflog` command.

```
$ git reflog                       # copy the commit-sha of merge state
$ git reset --soft <commit-sha>

$ git status                       # see the undo changes
```

N.B. If you do `--soft reset` then the changes of the commits you back exists in your working directory.

Comment: I was asking about something similar to `reset --soft`, not `reset --hard`

Comment: you can do `--soft reset` here, in that case undo changes exists in your working directory.

Comment: I don't want to go back to a particular commit, I'd like to get back to the merge state.

Comment: Yes, you have a `commit-sha for merge`. By `git log` or `git reflog` you can see easily **"Merge branch '***' of...** similar commit message. Then copy the `commit-sha` and back to the merge state.

Comment: I'd like to do `blah; git commit` and re-create that merge commit. What you propose allows me to do `git commit --amend`, not create a new commit for the merge.

Comment: Using commit --amend will produce the same output and is easier.

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --soft HEAD^` is a synonym for `git reset --soft HEAD^1` which means reset softly to the first parent. If it is the second parent (second parent != grandparent, that would be HEAD~2) you want to reset to, use `git reset --soft HEAD^2`. Alternatively you can of course also do `git reset --soft @{1}` which means the first entry in the reflog of the current branch if the merge was the last thing you did.

Comment: That won't take me back to the merge state. I'd like to be able to re-create that merge commit again.

Comment: Is maybe `git commit --amend` what you are really after? What do you want to achieve? Add some changes to the merge commit or resolve some conflict in another way, then `git commit --amend` definitely is what you are after.