# Git: Created a hot fix using incorrect branch

Tags: git

I have a master branch, and a develop branch.  My production environment uses the master branch, and the develop branch is usually several commits ahead.

I needed to add a quick patch to production. What I would normally do is:

- git checkout master
- git checkout -b my-hot-fix
- (make my hotfix changes, and commit them)
- git checkout develop
- git merge my-hot-fix
- git checkout master
- git merge my-hot-fix

In this case, I accidentally forget step 1, which means that I was on the develop branch when I created my-hot-fix.  I didn't realise this until I got to the last step, and merged the hot fix into master.  Instead of getting one small change, I received a number of prior commits from the develop branch.

How do I reverse this?  Note that I have not pushed the changes upstream yet.

Note: there are other SO questions about accidental merging.  My problem is more than that - it came about because the branch I am merging was created from the wrong branch.

Comment: Refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet)

Comment: Duplicate indeed, we can vote on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to simply reset your changes on both the `master` and `develop` to be in sync with the remote. So presuming your remote is called `origin`:

`git checkout master && git reset --hard origin/master`

`git checkout develop && git reset --hard origin/develop`

Then you can create a new hotfix branch from master this time and `git cherry-pick` the commit you want like so:

Find the commit hash:

`git log my-hot-fix`

Then:

`git cherry-pick MY_COMMIT_HASH`

Then you can continue from step 4 (git checkout develop) onwards.

You're fortunate in that you haven't pushed yet. You might want to look at the `git reflog` command also if you're ever stuck and want to revert local changes. It's really powerful! https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Comment: Thanks Stuart.  FYI, I have to use origin/master, and origin/develop (not origin master, origin develop).  Could be useful to update your answer.

Comment: Thanks @KimPrince, typo on my part and will fix :)

Answer (score 2):

To get your commit on the right branch :

```
# in the output of next command, spot the commit you know is good and store its hash ID, let's call it <commit_hash_OK>
git log -10 --oneline master

# in the output of next command, spot the NEW hotfix commit and store its hash ID, let's call it <commit_hash_NEW>
git log -10 --oneline my-hot-fix

# we need to reset master to its previous state
git checkout master
git reset --hard <commit_hash_OK>

# finally, put onto master only the commit you needed
git cherry-pick <commit_hash_NEW>
```

Then you'll be set on local, just push as usual.

Answer (score 1):

If changes are not pushed, you can cancel the commit with `git reset` command