# how to revert git merge and get your old code back?

Tags: git

I pull code from the master branch and merge that code in my branch. But now I want to revert that merge. How can I do that? 
How can I get my branch code back and undo all changes that happened after merging the master branch?

Comment: so many answers to the question already, here you go https://stackoverflow.com/a/2389423/1457270

Comment: Have you committed your code before you pulled the master branch?