# Git - how to roll back merge action?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

```
master branch
feature branch: created from master branch
dev branch: created from feature branch
```

I merged dev branch to feature branch by mistake, now I have to roll back feature branch. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just did the merge (of `dev` to `feature`), you could ["Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2389423/6309) with a [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset), especially if you have not pushed the `feature` branch yet.

```
git switch feature
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Make sure you don't have any work in progress.
And check with `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --branches` that your feature branch history is indeed showing the merge commit as the most recent one.