# revert the branch in a git to the previous commit in the same branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit, git-revert

I want to undo merge commit in the branch [image: in this picture]

from e6a49a..... to 4dea6ee.... 
There was conflicts in 6 files and I have resolved those and committed but when I try creating the Pull request it shoes me more than 100 of files of whole project which shouldn't be happening . Just guess may be the files types might have changes. so Just wanted to revert the merge commit. How can i do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit) or [undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet).

Answer (score 0):

- git reset --soft HEAD~1(I assume it's last commit)
- git status(to see which files are affected)
- git reset file_name(s)(ex: git reset test.py)
- git push origin branch_name -f