# How to fully rebase all commits in master branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a Github repository which originally had two branches master and dev.
I merged the dev branch, deleted it and now I only have one master branch.
The `git log --oneline --all --graph` output looks like this:

[image: git log]

I was expecting to have only one "line" of commits, how can I fix it?

Comment: "I was expecting to have only one "line" of commits" Can you elaborate on this? What problem is to be solved here? (No merge will produce the result you expected. `git merge` is creating a new commit, no past commit will be changed in any way by a merge.)

Comment: You didn't delete the branch; you delete the branch *head*, which was just a pointer to a particular commit, in this case a merge commit with 2 parents.

Comment: @Romain: I just want to have only one clean branch. e.g. commit `c3cee86` would be at the same level than its parent.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just need to undo that last merge commit? The easiest option is probably using the `squash` option for merging:

See [git-merge docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html):

> --squash
>
> > Produce  the  working  tree  and index state as if a real merge happened, but do not actually make a  commit  or  move  the  HEAD,  nor record  `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD`  to cause the next git commit command to create a merge commit. This allows you to create a *single commit*  on top  of  the  current  branch  whose  effect  is the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).

Just [undo the merge commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet) and then remerge with the `--squash` option enabled.