# How to make orphan branch as master?

Tags: git, github

Initially, I had two branches.

```
-->A-->B-->C [master]<-Head
             [v1]
```

So here `master` and `v1` are at the same place and master is `head`.

Now, I created an orphan branch `v2`. It has completely different codebase, the same application on new stack say older one on react and later one on vue.

```
-->A-->B-->C [master]<-Head
             [v1]

-->X-->Y-->Z[v2]
```

Now I want to make v2 as the master branch, as I consider production always must be master, so what I want in the end is.

```
-->A-->B-->C [v1]<-Head

-->X-->Y-->Z [master]<-Head 
             [v2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning:** This will delete anything on master that hasn't been committed to `v1` yet. You may want to commit or back up some files first.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard v2
```

Also you don't really need duplicate branches, and tags work fine for versions, so I'd recommend cleaning up your branches first:

```
git checkout v1
git tag v1
git checkout master
git branch -d v1
git branch -d v2
```

Comment: These will only be at local. Remote asking to merge with the code on remote.

Comment: Then run `git push --force-with-lease` when you're ready to update the remote `master` branch.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: `git reset --hard ...` will discard any uncommitted changes (staged or unstaged alike).

Warning 2: Although you just move a branch and don't modify any commits, this amounts to rewriting the history of `master` (actually, completely replacing the history of `master` with a different one). If you'll force-push the result to a shared or public repo that already had the history of the previous master branch, the [usual caveats](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#problems-With-rewriting-history) about [history rewriting](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) apply. See also [What are the practical consequences of rewriting Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1491001/674064)

```sh
git checkout master
git reset --hard v2
```

or

```sh
git checkout master
git reset --hard Z
```