# How to merge two commits from different branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

let say i have a commit 1 which is already present in branch A. I have a new commit 2 in branch B, i want to move this commit 2 to branch A and merge with commit 1.

Comment: Did you try using `git merge` with the `--ff-only` or `--no-ff` flags? Having the A branch checked out, it will merge the second commit from the B branch only (since the first commit is shared for two branches, that however contradicts with the title of your question).

Comment: @fluffy That only works if branch B's only difference with branch A is commit 2, which is a big assumption. Sai, by "merge" do you actually mean "squash" (combine the changes from the two commits into a single commit)?

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes that by "merge", you actually meant "squash", given the way you used it in your question.

> ⚠️ Doing the following will [rewrite history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491001/what-are-the-practical-consequences-of-rewriting-git-history).

(replace refs below with actual commit hashes and branch names)

#### to move `commit-2` to branch `branch-A`:

```sh
git rebase --onto branch-A commit-2^ commit-2
```

#### to squash `commit-2` into `commit-1`:

1. Use interactive rebase to redo the commit history beginning with `commit-1`

   ```sh
   git rebase -i commit-1^ branch-A
   ```
2. In the interactive rebase commit list, move the line for `commit-2` so that it immediately follows `commit-1`.
3. On the line for `commit-2`, replace the word `pick` with either `squash` or `fixup`. From the `git help rebase`:

   > If you want to fold two or more commits into one, replace the command "pick" for the second and subsequent commits with "squash" or
   > "fixup". If the commits had different authors, the folded commit will be attributed to the author of the first commit. The suggested
   > commit message for the folded commit is the concatenation of the first commit’s message with those identified by "squash" commands,
   > omitting the messages of commits identified by "fixup" commands, unless "fixup -c" is used. In that case the suggested commit message is
   > only the message of the "fixup -c" commit, and an editor is opened allowing you to edit the message. The contents (patch) of the "fixup
   > -c" commit are still incorporated into the folded commit. If there is more than one "fixup -c" commit, the message from the final one is
   > used. You can also use "fixup -C" to get the same behavior as "fixup -c" except without opening an editor.
4. Save and close the rebase commit list. `git rebase` will now apply the commits in the order you saw in the list. You will have to deal with any merge conflicts.

`git rebase -i` is one of the most powerful and useful commands in git. Learn it!