# Reverting multiple commits in the middle of master

Tags: git, git-revert, git-cherry-pick

`G1-B1-G2-G3-G4-G5-G6-G7-B2-G8-G9`

I have above commit already in `master`.

What's the best way to revert **B1** and **B2** from above commit?
And re-pushed to `master`.

Reset and cherry-pick seems quite a bit of jobs.
Just want to find a better and simple option to do this.

Comment: You can delete them from an interactive rebase.

Comment: When you say "best", how do you measure whether a solution is better than another?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I undo pushed commits using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/how-can-i-undo-pushed-commits-using-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way would be to issue two [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) commands:

```bash
git revert B1
git revert B2
```

That would create two new commits, negative images of B1, and B2, allowing you to do a simple git push (no force needed, no "history rewrite")

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the commits but revert their changes, see [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73033049/14637).

If you want to rewrite history and exterminate these commits as if they never existed, you can use an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i G1
```

Delete the lines for B1 and B2 in your text editor, save, exit, and they'll be removed from history. The [usual caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1491001/14637) when rewriting history apply.